# cython implementation of groupby failing with NameError

Tags: python-3.x, pandas-groupby, cython

I am attempting to speed up dozens of calls I make to pandas groupby using cython optimised functions. These incldue straight groupby, groupby with ranking and others. I have one that does a groupby that runs in my notebook, but not when called I get a NameError.

Here is the test code from my notebook (in 3 cells there)

```
%%cython
def _set_indices(keys_as_int, n_keys):
    import numpy

    cdef int i, j, k
    cdef object[:, :] indices = [[i for i in range(0)] for _ in range(n_keys)]

    for j, k in enumerate(keys_as_int):
        indices[k].append(j)
    return [([numpy.array(elt) for elt in indices])]



def group_by(keys):
    _, first_occurrences, keys_as_int = np.unique(keys, return_index=True, return_inverse=True)
    n_keys = max(keys_as_int) + 1
    indices = [[] for _ in range(max(keys_as_int) + 1)]
    print(str(keys_as_int) + str(n_keys) + str(indices))
    indices = _set_indices(keys_as_int, n_keys)
    return indices



%%timeit
result = group_by(['1', '2', '3', '1', '3'])
print(str(result))
```

The error I get is:

```
<ipython-input-20-3f8635aec47f> in group_by(keys)
  4     indices = [[] for _ in range(max(keys_as_int) + 1)]
  5     print(str(keys_as_int) + str(n_keys) + str(indices))
 ----> 6     indices = _set_indices(keys_as_int, n_keys)
      7     return indices

NameError: name '_set_indices' is not defined
```

Can someone explain if this is due to notebook or if I have done something wrong with the way cython is used, I am new to it.

Also any hints to get a strongly type, with minimum cache hits solution are most welcome.

Comment: Sorry, please don't just change the question, if you have a new problem you can post another question.

Comment: And you can't just add a new function `set_inidices()` that calls `_set_indices()`, you just moved the problem around as to what name is missing in the cell with `group_by()` in it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put your `_set_indices` function *in the same cell*, or you need to explicitly import it. From the [*Compiling with a Jupyter Notebook* documentation](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/source_files_and_compilation.html#compiling-with-a-jupyter-notebook):

> Note that each cell will be compiled into a separate extension module.

After compilation, you do have a global name `_set_indices`, but that doesn't make it available as a global in the *separate* extension module for the `group_by()` function.

You'll need to put the two function definitions into the same cell, or create a separate module for the utility functions.

Note that there is also another issue with the code; you can't just create a typed memory view from a list of integers:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "so58378716.pyx", line 22, in init so58378716
    result = group_by(['1', '2', '3', '1', '3'])
  File "so58378716.pyx", line 19, in so58378716.group_by
    indices = _set_indices(keys_as_int, n_keys)
  File "so58378716.pyx", line 6, in so58378716._set_indices
    cdef object[:, :] indices = [[i for i in range(0)] for _ in range(n_keys)]
  File "stringsource", line 654, in View.MemoryView.memoryview_cwrapper
  File "stringsource", line 349, in View.MemoryView.memoryview.__cinit__
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'list'
```

You'd have to create an actual numpy array, or use a [`cython.view.array` object](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/memoryviews.html#cython-arrays), or an [`array.array`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html).

Comment: I have added the declaring function for the ```_set_indices``` code above. But am struggling to get the array.array initialization of indices working. According to the documentation array can only support basic values i.e. not arrays.

Comment: @Olddave: nope, so you can't use an array to create arbitrary-length nested structures. Neither can you do this in numpy, so your whole premise is flawed.

Comment: @Olddave: it sounds as if you want to read [Is there any numpy group by function?](//stackoverflow.com/q/38013778) however.

Comment: So could I work out the maximum length of the contained arrays and use a 3 dimensional array to do my ranking function?

Comment: @Olddave: I don't know what you are trying to do with this groupy function, sorry.